# Create multiple slide boxes which trigger each other - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Still very fresh when it comes to Ionic and Angular. I'm currently designing a screen which is essentially split into 3 parts.

I currently have a slide box in the bottom green part, and I would like to associate it with the top green part, such that if you slide one rectangle, the other will slide too. However I want the middle orange part to remain static.

What are the options?

- multiple slide boxes, multiple controllers (if so, how to share data?)
- nested slide boxes
- one slide box with a template allowing a static part?
- got it completely wrong?

  [image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve it. I used two separate slide boxes. In between I have the rest of my  or whatever  you have. No nested slide boxes whatsoever. The key to solve this is to add the delegate-handle attribute to each of the . Giving the handles a unique or same name does not matter. I was thinking of keeping the handles with a unique name for more manageable code.